# Mixing Java with Scala to use a mutable TreeMap

Tags: scala, sorting, treemap, mutable

In Java I can do something like the following:

```
TreeMap<Double, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
```

If I want it sorted in reverse order, I can provide a Comparator such as:

```
class ReverseOrder implements Comparator<Object> {

    public ReverseOrder() {

    }

    public int compare(Object o1,Object o2) {
        Double i1=(Double)o1;
        Double i2=(Double)o2;
        return -i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

And instantiate the object as

```
TreeMap<Double, MyObject> myMap = new TreeMap<Double, MyObject>()(new ReverseOrder());
```

If I want to create the mutable Java TreeMap from within Scala, I can do something like this:

```
var treeMap = new java.util.TreeMap[Double,MyObject]
```

How do I implement the Java comparator in Scala so that I can sort based on ascending or descending order? Here, I'm assuming that I can't mix the Scala Ordering trait with the Java collection. Also, does anyone know if/when a mutable TreeMap is going to be available in Scala?

Comment: General advice: consult the Scala API first before you head over to Java implementations.

Comment: @Raphael.  Good advice in general.  However, I am currently still completely overwhelmed by the Scala API.  I also know from looking around that there is currently no mutable Scala TreeMap. My preference would be to remain purely with Scala, but this seems to be one of those cases where I have no choice but to include some Java.

Comment: The lack of a mutable SortedMap has struck me, too, some weeks ago. Someone should add one. Or anyone knows of a library that has one?

Comment: Huh, indeed. There is also no mutable `SortedSet`. Strange; I bet there is something in the pipeline. Well, make sure you really really need mutability. Coming from OO/imperative programming, you can easily fool yourself into believing you did when your really aren't.

Comment: A ticket has been issued for this, and assigned to the community - http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4147. Anyone that knows how to code a good mutable Red-Black tree in Scala/Java, or an efficient alternative, is welcome to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Ordering`, and define `ReverseOrder` like this:

```
case class ReverseOrder[T: Ordering] extends Comparator[T] {
  def compare(o1: T, o2: T) = -implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(o1, o2)
}

val treeMap = new TreeMap[Double, String](ReverseOrder[Double])
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like it might need to explicitly be case class ReverseOrder[T: Ordering] extends java.util.Comparator[T] {

Comment: @Bruce: it also can be normal (non-case) class, but then you need to write this boring `new` keyword like: `new ReverseOrder[Double]` :)

Comment: No need to define a class - just use `Ordering.reverse`. See answer by @Mike . Or use `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder()`.

Comment: Is TreeMap mutable? How we can implement this with a mutable implementation?

Answer (score 4):

The Scala trait `Ordering` extends the Java interface `Comparator`, so you can do this concisely:

```
val treeMap = new java.util.TreeMap[Double, String](Ordering.Double.reverse)
```